# margin-right not working when using columns property

Tags: css

I am trying to apply columns css on  so that I can show the content in pages horizontally. But when I set padding-right on body. I found it didn't work? Why?
Also, some times, there is blank column at the end

```
body{
height: 200px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-column-width: 608px;
-webkit-column-gap: 160px;
padding: 80px 80px 100px 80px;
```

}

updated to reply @jimjimmy1995

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.div{
height: 344px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-column-width: 608px;
-webkit-column-gap: 160px;
}   
body{
margin: 80px 80px 100px 80px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='div'>
<p> blablablabla. </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use the column property for layout as it is intended for use elements containing inline elements and text rather than block elements. There are several ways which allow you to achieve a similar effect such as using `display:inline;` or `float:left`.

In response to your question, you may need to specify a width to the body. Also note that your column width is rather large so may not fit two columns on the line:. The total width of two columns in with your styles is `80px+608px+160px+608px+80px=1536px` which is larger than most peoples monitors.

I would suggest creating a jsfiddle so we can see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I am developing a epub reader on ios. I use columns to do the pagination. I need this css property to dynamic split contents into columns(pages).  I want to set margin of body, but the margin-right doesn't work

Comment: I would use a wrapper div and apply the columns to that. You shouldn't have a problem then applying margin/padding to the body as needed.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: You missed the closing `div` tag. Probably what is causing the problem.

Comment: sorry, just a typo when I post the update. I have the </div> in my local and it still doesn't work. Are you sure these is a solution to fix this margin thing?

Comment: Ahh I see the problem now. Add `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: hidden`. http://jsfiddle.net/kYP37/

Comment: Can also use `overflow-y: scroll` so it only scrolls vertically.